# Is AWS using ApproximateReceiveCount to determine whether message has reached its retry count?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, dlq

We are building an application that reads messages from a SQS standard queue. The maxReceiveCount is configured to 5. We are reading ApproximateReceiveCount attribute in the app and doing certain operation if the service is processing the message for the 5th time.
I know sometimes the ApproximateReceiveCount is not accurate, the question is does AWS SQS also use this ApproximateReceiveCount attribute to decide whether to move message to DLQ? If so we are guaranteed to complete the operation correctly even if the ApproximateReceiveCount number is not accurate.

I have tried to search AWS SQS docs online but could not find the answer.